# 401 Login Required Error in Google analytics API data retrieval

Tags: php, google-oauth

I'm working with google analytics API to retrieve the click count for an application. I have tried with various answers in the site and am still having no success.

First I've download the google api using the github and create a OAuth 2.0 client IDs and create the json file with return path as `localhost/ProjectFolderName`. In my sample file I have connect the auto load path as follows.

**Error**

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
```

Comment: Error MessageFatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}'

Comment: could you please [edit] your question and add the link to "github" you used and also please include your comment as part of the question